# Customize Compass working between two locations?

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, gps, compass-geolocation

I have one requirement in which i want to show the arrow towards destination location from current location.Also it should move as per the device rotation and should point to same location after location also.Is it possible ? How?

I have refereed this link Rotating an Image View like a compass (with the "north pole" set elsewhere) but its not working for me. Any help?